# JMX on IBM JRE in Windows 7 wont work

Tags: java, windows-7, jmx

We are running an application using IBM JRE 1.5.0_SR12_FP4 on Windows 7 and trying to get JMX monitoring on it.

If we run the application using the SUN JVM then JMX monitoring works perfectly and we can connect to it.

However when using the IBM one, which we have to use, the application still starts up fine but JMX does not start up.

Has anyone encountered anything similar and found a workaround?

Comment: WebSphere server or standalone application?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including the Sun JMX libraries on your bootclasspath?
This would force the Sun implementation over the IBM.

Can you use a later JVM that version 5? That is really very very old!